# IndexedPageItemView not returning items when using an offset from the beginning

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

We have a new application in the works where we use streaming subscriptions to read emails as they come to our mailbox. Since we would like to read all past emails (roughly 50,000) we need some way of manually finding them instead of relying on the on notification event provided by EWS. The plan is to serialize the list of emails we read and parse for future database testing scenarios. I originally posted this question on StackOverflow asking how to retrieve all emails from a mailbox regardless of which folder they're in. Essentially, the mailbox I'm after organizes emails by year, month and day. Issuing a `FindFolders()` operation yields around 1,300 folders. I would rather not have to issue a `FindItems()` operation for every folder as it would take hours upon hours to read every email. Henning Krause mentioned that the managed API does not support querying Exchange for emails that are in a given list of parent folder ids. Instead I would have to use the `FindItem` operation. After some testing around I was able to retrieve my limit of items (1,000). Since the `FindItem` operation doesn't outright return if there are more items for your query I had to simply check that if the `FindItem` operation return 1,000 items then it was safe to query again until the result count is less than 1,000. Each loop through I increment my offset by 1,000.

When my offset is set to 0 I get the first 1,000 emails with no issues. On the second iteration I set my offset to 1,000 and receive no items, yet the operation was a success. Here is what I receive when setting an offset. If it matters I'm offsetting from the beginning. Below you can see one of the many `FindItemResponseMessage` nodes that clearly show there are 29 items in the view and that they all shown.

```
<m:FindItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
  <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
  <m:RootFolder IndexedPagingOffset="29" TotalItemsInView="29" IncludesLastItemInRange="true">
    <t:Items />
  </m:RootFolder>
</m:FindItemResponseMessage>
```

What am I missing?

Thank you.